# Date of last change of an InnoDB table structure

Tags: mysql, innodb, datetime, alter-table

I was wondering how to determine when was the last change (`ALTER TABLE...`) done to a given table.

An [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated) is available but unfortunately that doesn't work for InnoDB tables.

Would this work, looking at the `frm` file date time?

```
-rw-r-----   1 mysql    mysql       18622 Oct 24 21:07 mysql/data/mydb/mytable.frm
-rw-r-----   1 mysql    mysql     2114688 Oct 28 06:26 mysql/data/mydb/mytable.ibd
```

`Oct 24 21:07` seems to roughly correspond to the last time a change in the structure was performed.
Is that reliable information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say yes because any `ALTER TABLE` must change the timestamp of the last write to `.frm`.

To pull the UNIXTIME out, you would do this

```
ls -l --time-style=+"%s" mysql/data/mydb/mytable.frm | awk '{print $6}'
```

or to get the date time

```
ls -l --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" mysql/data/mydb/mytable.frm | awk '{print $6,$7}'
```

MySQL does provide an `UPDATE_TIME` column, but that's for changes to data or indexes.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding `UPDATE_TIME`, that doesn't work for InnoDB tables anyway...

Comment: UPDATE_TIME only works for MySQL 5.7 against InnoDB.

Comment: Hmm using 5.7.20 and the result of [that query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307488/338904) is `NULL`

Comment: @ringø - That's talking about `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, not `ls -l`.

Comment: @RickJames My comment is referring to a query, not `ls`. Thanks anyway, now I know the command to get the table last update.